# Query Builder - laravel

Tags: laravel

Con la siguiente consulta:

```
public function getChartOperator(Request $request)
    {   
        $anio = date('Y');
        $month = date('m');

        $ordenes = DB::table('orders as o')        
            ->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(o.date) as mes'),
                    DB::raw('YEAR(o.date) as anio'),    
                    DB::raw('(o.status) as estado'),
                    DB::raw('(o.user_id) as user_id'),                
                    DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))     

        ->whereYear('o.date', $anio)
        ->whereMonth('o.date', $month)
        ->where('o.status', 'TERMINADO')       


        ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.status)'),DB::raw('YEAR(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.user_id)'))
        ->get();    

        return ['estados' => $ordenes, 'anio' => $anio];             
    }
```

obtengo este resultado

```
{
"estados": [
{
"mes": "diciembre",
"anio": 2019,
"estado": "TERMINADO",
"user_id": 4,
"total": 2
},
{
"mes": "diciembre",
"anio": 2019,
"estado": "TERMINADO",
"user_id": 6,
"total": 1
},
{
"mes": "diciembre",
"anio": 2019,
"estado": "TERMINADO",
"user_id": 7,
"total": 1
}
],
"anio": "2019"
}
```

lo que prentendo mostrar es el nombre de usuario y no el user_id, este nombre se encuentra en la tabla users y su campo es name, entonces ¿como puedo relacionar el campo name que pertenece a la tabla users con mi consulta actual? y asi obtener el nombre del usuario

Esta es mi tabla orders:

[image: orders]

Answer (score 0):

**Opción 1**

- Usa el método `join` para generar la relación entre la tabla `orders` y la tabla `users`
- Una vez hecho lo anterior, usa otro método `select` para elegir el nombre del usuario
- Considera mudar tu consulta a Eloquent, la haría mas simple con las relaciones y mas fácil de leer y mantener

Código

```
public function getChartOperator(Request $request)
    {   
        $anio = now()->year;
        $month = now()->month;

        $ordenes = DB::table('orders as o')   
            ->select('users.name')  /*aqui el nuevo select*/   
            ->select(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(o.date) as mes'),
                    DB::raw('YEAR(o.date) as anio'),    
                    DB::raw('(o.status) as estado'),
                    DB::raw('(o.user_id) as user_id'),                
                    DB::raw('COUNT(*) as total'))     
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id') /*aquí el join*/
        ->whereYear('o.date', $anio)
        ->whereMonth('o.date', $month)
        ->where('o.status', 'TERMINADO')       


        ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.status)'),DB::raw('YEAR(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.user_id)'))
        ->get();    

        return ['estados' => $ordenes, 'anio' => $anio];             
    }
```

**Opción 2**

- Para esta opción deberás tener creado al menos el modelo **`Order`**
- Considera que si estas trabajando con Laravel, el mismo ya trae a *Carbon* una biblioteca para el manejo de fechas
- Para obtener el año actual es mucho mas simple de este modo: **`now()->year`**
- Para obtener solo el número de mes actual lo haces así: **`now()->month`**

Quedando así:

```
$anio = now()->year;
$month = now()->month;

$ordenes = Order::selectRaw('users.name, 
                            MONTHNAME(orders.date) AS Mes,
                            YEAR(orders.date) AS Anio,
                            orders.status AS Estado,
                            orders.user_id AS user_id,
                            COUNT(*) AS Total')
            ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'orders.user_id')
            ->whereYear('orders.date', $anio)
            ->whereMonth('orders.date', $month)
            ->where('orders.status', 'TERMINADO')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw('MONTHNAME(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.status)'),DB::raw('YEAR(o.date)'),DB::raw('(o.user_id)'))
            ->get();
```

Comment: estoy probando lo que me indicaste, obtengo este error: ```"SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'orders.user_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: select MONTHNAME(o.date) as mes, YEAR(o.date) as anio, (o.status) as estado, (o.user_id) as user_id, COUNT(*) as total from `orders` as `o` inner join `users` on `users`.`id` = `orders`.`user_id` where year(`o`.`date`) = 2019 and month(`o`.`date`) = 12 and `o`.`status` = TERMINADO group by MONTHNAME(o.date), (o.status), YEAR(o.date), (o.user_id)) ◀"```

Comment: ok estoy manejando la opcion 1 estoy viendo y pregunto tendria que hacer otro ```$ordenes = DB::table('orders as o')   
            ->select('users.name')  /*aqui el nuevo select*/``` pero en este caso con users hablo de esto: ```$usuarios = DB::table('users as u')   ``` ?

Comment: En mi segunda opción revisa la modificación se me habia pasado un detalle en las comillas @RodrigoRuiz